# XamlObjectWriterException: Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}Ribbon'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, f#, ribbon

I get this exception when I am adding the Ribbon control in a wpf application. Can someone give me some advice on how to get past it? In my xaml code the ribbon is added in the last tab as you can see on the code that follows. Everything was working normally and the problems started when I added the ribbon.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Views;assembly=DemoDataGrid"
Title="Testing GUI app" Width="1200" Height="768">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFEAF1FB">
        <MenuItem Header="File" IsTabStop="False">
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding FileExit}" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Tools" IsTabStop="False"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Help" IsTabStop="False"/>
    </Menu>
    <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="1" Background="DarkGray"/>
    <UserControl Grid.Row="2" IsTabStop="False">
        <TabControl Margin="10,50,10,10">
            <TabItem Header="Date Picker">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <v:DatePickerView/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Color Picker">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <v:ColorPickerView/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Combo Box">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <v:ComboBoxView/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="ExtendedDataGrid">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <v:DGridXtendedView/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="RibbonMenu">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Ribbon/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </UserControl>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Background="#FFEAF1FB">
        <StatusBarItem Content="{Binding User}"/>
        <Separator />
        <StatusBarItem Content="{Binding Status}"/>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're missing an assembly reference.

Comment: Can you show us some xaml code?

Comment: I edited the original post with xaml code

Comment: Do you use FsXAML?

Comment: Yes I use FsXAML.

Comment: @MikeF Do you use [Fluent.Ribbon](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon)?

Comment: (please, use `@Foggy`  in your comment to notify me)

Comment: @Foggy no I use the standard ribbon that is provided

Comment: can you provide MCVE?

Comment: @Foggy I don't know what an MCVE is

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: or you can just point me out where I can read about "standard" ribbon

Comment: @Foggy I'm using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon if that's what you want to know

Comment: Did you add references to `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll` ?

Comment: @Foggy No I didn't . That's the fault? How do I add the reference?

Comment: `Project` -> `Add references` -> `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`

Comment: btw, I advise you join to [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/)

Comment: @Foggy thanks for all your comments but the reference was not the reason. Maybe I should create a RibbonWindow instead of a window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.
Add reference to `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`

2.
Add namespace to your xaml file

```
xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
```